# Meaning of 瞳だけはぶっ飛ばない

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs, metaphor

Context: in a gym, a boxer attacks another boxer saying that he was provoking him with his eyes. After punching him, he thinks:

> **瞳だけはぶっ飛ばねー**でやんの
>   甘ちゃんのクセに
>
> 人殴って拳が潤わなかったなんて
>   ねーのに……

What is the meaning of the verb ぶっ飛ぶ when it refers to the eyes? Looking at its meanings in the dictionary I couldn't find one that fits the context. Is it used metaphorically here?

Also, could you please explain the grammar behind ぶっ飛ばねーでやんの? Is it the contracted form of ぶっ飛ばないでやるの?

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:** since it looks like a strange metaphor, I uploaded the original pages to provide more context.

[Pages where the fight starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiwbQ.jpg) (here 瞳 is used with め furigana)

[Pages with the sentence in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWiT7.jpg)

Comment: `甘ちゃんクセに` -- 「甘ちゃん**の**くせに」？

Comment: @Chocolate You are right, I added the missing の, thank you!

Comment: You should indicate where the line breaks. And can't you at least notice there is a "contrast" in this sentence? You should not drop the previous sentences especially in a context like this.

Comment: @naruto I added the line break, thank you for suggesting that! I can see the contrast expressed by くせに, but still can't make sense of the verb ぶっ飛ぶ in this context. I think I understand the rest of the sentence, my attempt would be "Even though he is just a wimp that ......, beating someone is always a good thing for [my] fists". Anyway, I edited the question adding more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 瞳だけはぶっ飛ばねー has the similar meanig of 目だけは死んでない, which means "He still has a fighting sprit (even if his body was damaged)." and "He hasn't yielded yet (even if his body was damaged)."　It isn't a common phrase.

As for the grammar, I found an explanation, and it says 「～でやがるの」changed to 「～でやんの」. やがる is used when you say about someone's action with contempt or hatred such as 学校来ねーでやがる.　About の, a dictionary says 断定の言い方を和らげる意を表す.

Comment: Is there any chance it refers to the fact that his eyes did not roll even though he was knocked out? Often when people get knocked out, their eyes will roll back or look in two different directions. I'm wondering if this is the meaning because 目がいきいきとしていなくて（きりっとしていなくて？）むしろ死んでいるように見えます。

Comment: @By137 I feel the eyes looks weird. The boxer who hit him may feel his weird fighting sprits. Of course, we can interpret it in some ways. but I focus on the sentense "甘ちゃんのクセに(despite a spoiled kid)".

Comment: I see the connection to 甘ちゃんのクセに now. Thanks!

Comment: @YuuichiTam I thought 甘ちゃん in this case means a wimp, a weak person. Could it be correct?

Comment: A dictionary says 甘ちゃん means 考え方や言動などが甘い、生ぬるい人を指して用いる表現。あるいは厳しさに欠けるさまなどを意味する表現。I came up with another word "naive". Wimp, weak, naive, softy, spoiled, these words are similar, aren't they?

Comment: @YuuichiTam Thank you for your explanations. Could you please provide your translation attempt for the whole sentence? I now understand the meaning of 瞳だけはぶっ飛ばねー, but I still struggle to link it with the second part of the sentence (人殴って拳が潤わなかったなんてねーのに).

Comment: I think 拳が潤わなかった is a strange way of saying and we can interpret it in some ways. In my opinion, it has the similar meaning of 人殴って満足しなかったことなんてないのに(I had always hit people until I was satisfied).

Answer (score 2):

Tbh the sentence doesn't make a lot of sense - it reads like somebody tried to incorporate many advanced vocabularies without really understanding how they are used. There are also a few grammatical mistakes.

Having said that, if I'm forced my guess would be that the opponent kept his gaze on the attacker, despite (other parts of the body) being punched away.

It's very hard to tell though, as 瞳 is overwhelmingly used for adorable things. An exception is when it's used to describe the pupil specifically, so it's possible but it's not obvious to me why the writer would focus on the pupil. It's also a physically odd situation (body moving away but the pupil remains?). ぶっ飛ぶ can also refer to blackouts, but then it's also odd (one is unconscious, but the pupil remains conscious?).

I think you'll have to ask the writer - maybe they knew what they wanted to express, but they are probably not yet proficient enough in Japanese to express it.

**EDIT:** After looking at the context, I suppose the writer is going for a VERY creative, unorthodox writing. They probably added the "め" in ふりがな because hitomi wouldn't fit (it will make things sound very adorable), but they still wanted to focus on the pupil. They also say "拳が潤う" which is extremely odd （潤う only refers to pleasant moisture), but it makes sense because the character then talks about erection... "潤わなかったなんてねーのに" is probably a misprint of "潤わなかったことなんてねーのに". I think you have to interpret it with your own creativity. It's not a common expression by any means and I guess you are meant to interpret it in your own way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The writer is Japanese, so I don't think is a matter of proficiency. Anyway, I added more context in the question.

Comment: I see, added a bit of edit @Marco

Comment: @Marco, to play devil's advocate, I've known plenty of Americans who can't really write English...  ;)